# Japanese language translation issue in CSV File - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, csv

I am facing an issue while exporting japanese text in CSV format. Junk characters are being exported instead of original japanese text. I am using .NET MVC FileStreamResult to export records in Csv file and used encoding format as UTF8 *(I have also used some other encoding format, but no luck)*. I debugged my code and able to convert string from memory stream and vice versa and able to see original japanese text being exported. Once exporting completed, I opened the CSV file, but only able to see junk character instead of expected text. If I open the CSV file in NotePad ***( Opening the csv file in Notepad is NOT my requirement. I am referring Notepad only to verify whether i am able to see Japanese translated language )***, then i can see the expected japanese text. It would be really helpful if someone please help me find root cause of this issue and provide a resolution.

Ex. **東京都品川区大崎** gets written as **æ±äº¬éƒ½å“å·åŒºå¤§å´Ž**

**Note: I can see expected japanese text is exported properly if I opened the sample .CSV file using LibreOffice Calc, Linux default gEdit. But the issue is with opening this csv file using MS Office.**

Please find the below attached code -

```
Controller/Action to execute while clicking on export to Csv button
================================================================================
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public FileStreamResult SaveCustomerInfo()
{
    return ExportToCsv();
}

================================================================================
private static FileStreamResult ExportToCsv()
{
    var exportedData = new StringBuilder();

    exportedData
        .AppendLine("実行日,口座番号,支店番号,アカウント名,支店名,の/受益秩序,ステートメント日,入力日,お問い合わせ番号, ,Date Range")
        .Append(
            "CS0001,Demo FName,Demo LName,8/20/2015,\"Demo User Address\",City,Country,08830,0123456789,15813,Absolute from 8/20/2015 to 8/22/2015");

    var stream = PrintingHelper.StringToMemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8, exportedData.ToString());
    var fileStreamResult = new FileStreamResult(stream, "text/csv")
                               {
                                   FileDownloadName =
                                       new StringBuilder("TestExportedFileInCsv")
                                       .Append(".csv").ToString()
                               };

    return fileStreamResult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sound as though you haven't installed the language pack for MS Office on the machine that you are trying to open the csv on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I export same record in excel & pdf, i am able to see japanese text while opening this file. Not sure what's wrong with csv file. We are passing html reference (tabular format) to Pdf Service to export records.

Comment: The code sample for exporting records in excel is quite similar to what we have for Csv EXCEPT passing tabular data and MIME Type.  Here is the sample code for excel format -

Comment: private static FileStreamResult ToExcel()
{
var html = EnsureSingleRootElement(printableGadget.RenderToString()); //Returns data in tabular form as below sample.
var stream = PrintingHelper.StringToMemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8, html);
 var fileStreamResult = new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/vnd.ms-excel")
        {
         FileDownloadName =
            new StringBuilder("TestExportedFileInCsv")
            .Append(".xls").ToString()
};

 return fileStreamResult;
}

Comment: Have you checked that the font you are using can support Japanese Characters

Comment: <html>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'>
<body>
 <div class="c-print_document-header">
  <div class="c-print-body">
   <table>
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>実行日</th><th>口座番号</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>

Comment: <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td style="mso-number-format:\@"><div class="c-print-container">
       CS0001
      </div></td><td style="mso-number-format:\@"><div class="c-print-container">
       Demo FName
      </div>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: In response to your earlier comment - I have verified and found that japanese language pack is not installed for MS Office. I can see the japanese text for pdf and excel while opening that file. So wondering whether it's required to install japanese language pack to view the Csv file ? Please suggest

Comment: Pdf is adobe and so works in a different way to Office. If you are opening the file in Excel and can see all Japanese Characters as expected then i'd assume quite surprisingly that you do not need the language pack. If it is just the CSV check as per my earlier comment that the font type can support Japanese as I think by default csv format uses a different font style to Excel and pdf. That all said it wouldn't hurt to put the language pack on.

Comment: I opened both Excel and Csv file and found that both of them are using font style as Calibri and font size as 11. Please suggest do I need to check anything else.

Comment: try adding \uFEFF to the beginning of the output file. There are some known issues with opening CSV files in Excel that use this type of Character set. If this doesn't work, what version of Office are you using

Comment: Sorry, could not understand your point. Do I need to add the \uFEFF to the beginning of file name (e.g - Test), so that it can appear as uFEFFTest ? Please advise on this. I am using MS Office 2010.

Comment: No it needs to go in the File in the first position. An easy way to prove this is to open Excel write some cells with Japanese and then save as .csv. Open the csv in say notepad and compare the Start of the file with the start of the file that you have written. Chances are there are some 'Header' characters e.g. \uFEFF. You also might be better trying to save as UTF-16 as opposed to UTF-8

Comment: UTF-16Le also make it tab delimited as opposed to comma. The \uFEFF is required this tells it the BOM (byte Order Mark)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have followed the above instructions. But unable to see japanese text in either .csv file Or when open the same .csv file in notepad. I can see only question mark ( ?????). Is this because of missing language pack ? Please suggest.

Comment: Thanks for the advise.